# How to grab latest mail with Python

Tags: python, email, google-api

I need a Python script which grabs and scraps latest mail message. After googling I have very few options:

1. Google Pub/Sub that sends webhook notification to my Flask configured server. As for me the easiest way but after reading official documentation I couldn't figure out if it's free or not;
2. Write a script using Python libraries such as poplib or imaplib. But in that case I won't be able to use gmail since google doesn't grant access to 3rd party apps.
   The question is which way will provide the best processing time cause I need to scrap incoming message as fast as possible?

The question is which way will provide the best processing time cause I need to scrap incoming message as fast as possible?